# Array Start From 1 not from 0

Tags: php, arrays

I got an array like this:

```
Array ( [Pembangunan] => 100 [Komputer] => 200 [Sekolah] => 300 [Osis] => 400 )
```

After that, I called it into foreach to insert to database but my result always like this:

```
INSERT INTO m_student_payment(sp_biaya, sp_jmlbiaya) VALUES ('Komputer', '100')
INSERT INTO m_student_payment(sp_biaya, sp_jmlbiaya) VALUES ('Sekolah', '100')
INSERT INTO m_student_payment(sp_biaya, sp_jmlbiaya) VALUES ('Osis', '100')
INSERT INTO m_student_payment(sp_biaya, sp_jmlbiaya) VALUES ('', '100')
```

**The key "Pembangunan" never called. Does anyone knows why? It looks like the index always start from 1**

Here's my code:

```
$item = $_POST['mexpense'];
$namexp = $_POST['namexp'];
$newarr = array();
$arr = array();
foreach ($namexp as $val)
{
    array_push($newarr, $val);
}   

foreach ($item as $val2)
{
    array_push($arr, $val2);
}

$arres = array_combine($newarr, $arr);
print_r($arres);
echo "<br />";
asort($arres);
foreach ($arres as $value)
{
    $qq = "INSERT INTO m_student_payment(sp_biaya, sp_jmlbiaya) VALUES ('".key($arres)."', '".remdot($value)."')";
    echo $qq."<br />";
    //mysqli_query($conn,$qq);
    next($arres);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You had `next($arres)` in `foreach` loop
- Iterate array using `foreach ($arres as $key => $value)` gives easy access to `$key` and `$value`

Updated Code

```
foreach ($arres as $key => $value)
{
    $qq = "INSERT INTO m_student_payment(sp_biaya, sp_jmlbiaya) VALUES ('".$key."', '".remdot($value)."')";
    echo $qq."<br />";
    //mysqli_query($conn,$qq);

    // REMOVE 
    //next($arres);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access key like example below,

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, i think this logic will help you

```
$cobaini =Array ( 'Pembangunan' => 100 ,'Komputer' => 200 ,'Sekolah' => 300 ,'Osis' => 400 ); 

foreach ($cobaini as $key => $nilai) {
    echo "INSERT INTO m_student_payment(sp_biaya, sp_jmlbiaya) VALUES ('".$key."','".$nilai."')";
    echo "<br>";
}
```

the result is

```
INSERT INTO m_student_payment(sp_biaya, sp_jmlbiaya) VALUES ('Pembangunan','100')
INSERT INTO m_student_payment(sp_biaya, sp_jmlbiaya) VALUES ('Komputer','200')
INSERT INTO m_student_payment(sp_biaya, sp_jmlbiaya) VALUES ('Sekolah','300')
INSERT INTO m_student_payment(sp_biaya, sp_jmlbiaya) VALUES ('Osis','400')
```